# Does Weak convergence in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ implies almost everywhere of the gradient $\nabla$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, variational-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $1<p<N$. Let $\{u_n\}$ in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ be such that
$$
u_n \rightharpoonup u \quad \text { in } W_0^{1, p}(\Omega) .
$$

Then, it is true that up to subsequence
$$
 \nabla u_n \rightarrow \nabla u,
$$
almost everywhere in $\Omega$
It was on my notes, so I guess it is true.

Could anyone help, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, for the same reason that weak convergence in $L^p$ does not imply pointwise convergence.

Comment: I believe that if $1 < p < N$ the convergence a.e holds, because the embedding $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^q(\Omega)$ is compact for $1 < p < N$, and $q < \frac{np}{n-p} = p^*$. We can use the fact that $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $W_0^{1,p}$ if and only if $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^p$ and $\nabla u_n \rightharpoonup \nabla u$ in $L^p$.

Comment: I didn't get the point of cmk in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723208/application-of-weak-convergence-in-sobolev-space-w-01-omega

Comment: Lp convergence does not imply almost everywhere: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-imply-convergence-almost-everywhere

Comment: @kilose2013 You only have convergence a.e. to $u$ up to some subsequence of $u_n$.

Comment: take a look, for example, at this question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792474/weak-convergence-implies-pointwise-convergence/4792479#4792479
there, you take $u'_n = f_n$ so that your $u_n$ is a sequence of sawtooth functions weakly converging to $0$.

Comment: @kilose2013 in the link you provided, $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{\Omega} \nabla (u_n - u) dx =0$ because $\nabla (u_n - u) $ is integrated against the constant function $1$, which is clearly in all $L^p$ when $|\Omega|<\infty$. We don't need a.e. convergence, just weak convergence suffices.

Comment: @ BigbearZzz  in the link: he sad that $\nabla u_n \rightarrow \nabla u $ in $L^1(\Omega)$ and thus up to subsequence  $\nabla u_n \rightarrow \nabla u $ a.e ?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Alright, get it from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792474/weak-convergence-implies-pointwise-convergence/4792479#4792479, thank you very much for helping